# Negligible sets

Tags: measure-theory

let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space, $\mu_1:\Sigma\to[0,\infty]$ and $\mu_2:\Sigma \to [0,\infty]$  be two measures and let $\mu=\mu_1+\mu_2$.

prove that $N \subseteq X$ is $\mu$ negligible if and only if $N$ is $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ negligible

it's easy to prove the necessary condition, in order to prove the sufficient condition I considerd the set 
$E$ $\mu_1$-null and the set $F$ $\mu_2$-null such that $N \subset E$ and $N \subset F$
now how can I find a set $G$ that is $\mu$-null such that $N\subset G$?

Comment: Hint: a 12-letter word beginning with "I".

Comment: Yes , I thought about the intersection of E and F, but what about mu1(E inter F) and mu2(E inter F)?

Comment: @MalakDiab: $E \cap F$ is a subset of $E$.  So how does $\mu_1(E \cap F)$ compare to $\mu_1(E)$?

Comment: @NateEldredge , thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(E∩F)⊂E → μ1(E∩F)≤μ1(E) → μ1(E∩F)=0 
(E∩F)⊂F → μ2(E∩F)≤μ2(F) → μ2(E∩F)=0 $
then $μ(E∩F)=μ1(E∩F)+μ2(E∩F)=0$ and $N⊂(E∩F)$ so $N$ is $μ$ negligible